# Hibernate giant query optimization

Tags: hibernate, optimization

I just got in charge of an application whose goal is to extract a large amount of data (up to 100,000 rows from a table containing 10,000,000 rows). Unfortunately, the extraction is written in Java + Hibernate and the performance is relatively poor. Extraction of 100,000 rows using Java + Hibernate takes approximately 1 minute and 30 seconds. Same extraction using [Talend](http://www.talend.com/) takes approximately 30 seconds (3 times less).

Here is a sample of what the code looks like:

```
Launcher.initStatelessSession();
Launcher.beginStatelessTransaction();

//Creation of the Criteria crit, no join, only a single table is read.
int fetchSize = 1000;
crit.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
crit.setCacheable(false);
crit.setReadOnly(true);

ScrollableResults result = crit.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
// Most of the time is spent from HERE ...
while (result.next()) {
   // Some code but insignificant time compared to the result.next().
   // I replaced this code with continue; and the speed did not really change.
}
// ... to HERE
```

Any idea on optimizations that could speed up this query? At the moment, there is no plan to abandon Hibernate for something else.

Comment: Knowing what the query is and how you create your Criteria would certainly help optimizing it.

Comment: I was in a very similar situation about two years ago. The main issue was that the domain had a lot of lazy collections that caused very, very many selects. This and also other performance issues got really easy pinpointed by profiling with JProfiler: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided details on how Hibernate is configured. How is the `Criteria` defined? How are the persisted objects defined? What is the code in your `while (result.next()) ...` block? These answers, and whatever other relevant details you may provide, will be valuable in getting a helpful answer.

Comment: It could help to switch on the sql tracing in hibernate with `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in the hibernate.cfg.xml, then you can see if the SQL statement generated by hibernate is fast or has some inconveniences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what talend is, but I suspect it to be some kind of database gui tool?

In this case what possibly might be the reason is that hibernate as to dehydrate the objects, i.e. checking that the retrieved object isn't yet in the session, create an instance and fill all properties (possibly with other referenced entities).

Use a profiler to find out what it is actually going on in greater detail

all this assumes that you actually executing the same sql statement. As mentioned in the comments, depending on your criteria and your mapping hibernate might create very 'interesting' select statements.